# Backbone save model timeout

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I’m trying to save model that requires like 40sec to process in backend
and also to wait for the response of saving but in my app there is some global timeout that catches this and displays generic error message.

So the question is can I set somehow timeout for my `model.save()` method?

I tried using

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    timeout: 30000
});
```

inside model initialize method and also tried passing timeout inside save method like this

```
myModel.save({  
    timeout: 30000  
},...
```

but it didn't work

Comment: *in my app there is some global timeout*  - where is this? frontend? backend? is the request being aborted on frontend by browser or is server responding with an error message (request complete, not aborted) ?

Answer (score 0):

40seconds is a lot , maybe a problem with your backend.

I'm not sure changing the global timeout is a good idea you would have to do it for every browser and it may not be the best option.

What I would do is keep an id in your app for the payload you try to save.

```
=> frontend calls saveMyPayload(payload, id)
=> frontend display loader
=> backend process payload (takes 40secondes)
```

Then you may call regularly your backend to ask if the saving is done.

```
=> frontend calls isMyPayloadSavedYet(id)
=> backend answer "no" until saving is done
=> finally backend answer "yes it's saved"
=> frontend displays "saved" message
=> frontend destroy the setInvervale used for saving verification
```

That's how I would do it (also maybe fix the slow backend if possible)

Hope it helps !